# Permission object with no emailAddress and with letter "k" at the end of ID

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download all permissions for given folderId using GoogleDrive API v3 in python. I'm trying to get:

- permission ID
- email address
- role

I'm using the call:

```
permissions().list(fileId=folder_id, fields="permissions(id), permissions(emailAddress), permissions(role)").execute()
```

Almost all permissions look as expected (contain id, address and role):

```
{'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx4921909', 'emailAddress': 'someemail@somedomain.com', 'role': 'writer'}
```

but one permission looks malformed:

```
{'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx0973323k', 'role': 'writer'}
```

Not only it has no `emailAddress` field but also contains letter `k` at the end of ID. Couldnt find any info in the documentation that would explain this permission object and what can it mean. My Google account also does not allow me to contact Google support.

Do you have an idea what can this permission mean?

I tried to search in the documentation - no info about such permission object.
I tried to contact Google support - but my account does not allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Drive API Response:

I understand you are getting a different result. Like this JSON Object result.
`{'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx0973323k', 'role': 'writer'}`

This is a result of a permission that was granted to a `Domain` inside your Organization.

I have replicated the same request on my test file which shows the same result.

```
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "id": "*****934360203522",
      "emailAddress": "someone@domain.com",
      "role": "writer"
    },
    {
      "id": "*******85668123645",
      "emailAddress": "someone@domain.com",
      "role": "reader"
    },
    {
      "id": "*********7854k",
      "role": "reader"
    },
    {
      "id": "*********72189503127",
      "emailAddress": "someone@domain.com",
      "role": "owner"
    }
  ]
}
```

With these results it just shows the difference between permission ID between Domain and Entity that have an email address.